# Find element in HTML string and replace with HTML table in C#

Tags: c#, html

I want to do, Find the html element from HTML string and replace with HTML table, please help to complete my task. thanks in advance

I have attach sample HTML and my code behind code, here I want to remove  tag with id `sample_id` in the HTML and add a table to that place in HTML string

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Getting started</h2>
            <p>
                ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
                enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup
                for enjoyable, agile development.
            </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
            <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
            <p>You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
       <span class="sample_class" id="sample_id"></span>
    </div>
```

```
public string ReplacePlaceHolder(string value)
{
     string HTMLToConvert = "";
     StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
     // Decode the encoded string.
     HTMLToConvert = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value).ToString();

     //HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
     //doc.LoadHtml(HTMLToConvert);
     //var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='placeholder']");

     string generatedHTMLtable = GenerateHTMLTable();
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(HTMLToConvert);

     builder.Replace("<span class='sample_class' id='sample_id'></span>", generatedHTMLtable);
     StringReader sr = new StringReader(builder.ToString());
     return sr.ToString();
}

//Sample method for generating string of HTML table
public string GenerateHTMLTable()
{
    string tableHtml = "";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("FirstTable");
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserID", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AccountID", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Code", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AccountName", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GroupCode", typeof(string)));

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
       DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
       dr["UserID"] = i;
       dr["AccountID"] = i + 1;
       dr["Code"] = "COD" + i;
       dr["AccountName"] = "Account" + i;
       dr["GroupCode"] = "GRP" + i;
       dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    tableHtml += "<table>";
    tableHtml += "<tr><th>UserID</th><th>AccountID</th><th>Code</th><th>AccountName</th><th>GroupCode</th></tr>";

    foreach (DataRow drAccount in dt.Rows)
    {
        tableHtml += "<tr><td>" + drAccount["UserID"] + "</td><td>" + drAccount["AccountID"] + "</td><td>" + drAccount["Code"] + "</td><td>" + drAccount["AccountName"] + "</td><td>" + drAccount["GroupCode"] + "</td></tr>";
    }
    tableHtml += "</table>";
    return tableHtml;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Replace `<span class="sample_class" id="sample_id"></span>` with whatever you want

Comment: @DaveS No errors, I need to know a way I tried so many way I couldn't complete this

Comment: @EpicKip i tried like this also but It not getting replacing,
stringbuilder.Replace("<span class='sample_class' id='sample_id'></span>", generatedHTMLtable);

Comment: it does not say placeholder for class and id is empty so that wont work....

Comment: why minus vote?? no I have edit my comment, I use same like that @EpicKip

Comment: I give a minus vote because you want to replace something and if it is truly as you say the code i gave would work. You're not telling us everything we need to help you, nothing about an error nothing. Maybe even content in the span, how would we know...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154445/discussion-between-shakir-ahamed-and-epickip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi currently I'm using this approach to complete my task, exactly this is what I want,I'm adding this is because of future user.

We can find the element using id or class and replace full element like below.

```
string ofRegex = "<span (class|id)=\"{0}\".*?>\\w*\\n";  // here I have added span tag, we can use any kind of HTML tag which is we need to replace
string finalRegex = string.Format(ofRegex, "sample_class"); // generating regex with class name

string generatedHTMLtable = GenerateHTMLTable();         //// Populate HTML table
htmlAfterREplace = Regex.Replace(HTMLToConvert, finalRegex, generatedHTMLtable);         ///Replace with generated table using rege
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `ToString()` on the `StringReader` and trying to return that.
In this case, that will return a string containing the name of the type (`System.IO.StringReader`). 
You don't need the `StringReader` at all, calling `ToString()` on the `StringBuilder` will output the string you are looking for.

However, since all you are doing is a string replacement, you don't need the `StringBuilder` anyway.

Also, as EricKip mentioned in his answer, the string passed to the `Replace` method does is not using the correct quotation marks.

This is a working version of your `ReplacePlaceHolder` method.

```
public string ReplacePlaceHolder(string value)
{
    var HTMLToConvert = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value)       
    return HTMLToConvert.Replace("<span class=\"sample_class\" id=\"sample_id\"></span>", GenerateHTMLTable());
}
```

Note that I have retained the `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` line, as we don't know what your `value` parameter is, so I don't know if it is needed.
However, it is used for decoding URLs, which probably isn't what you need. You might be looking for [HTML Decode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have use jquery method encodeURI to encode the string that's what I'm using UrlDecode method, HTML Decode is not working as I am expecting

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is trying to replace a span with the CSS class `placeholder`

`builder.Replace("<span class='placeholder'></span>", generatedHTMLtable);`

but your question states that you want to replace the element with the ID `sample_id`.

So, replace the line above with:

`builder.Replace("<span class="sample_class" id="sample_id"></span>", generatedHTMLtable);`

Incidentally, string replace isn't going to be a robust way to work with HTML if you want to do anything more complicated. There are options using the framework, or you might want to look at something like 
[HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net)

Comment: Yeah I already said that as a comment but that "din't work" either. So I suggest just leaving it alone

Comment: Thanks for your help *HTML Agility Pack*, Replace is not working as per the my code,I have edit my question @Dave

Comment: Can you give some more information? This isn't enough to help. What are you passing in to `ReplacePlaceholder`?

Comment: @DaveS try this `"<span class="sample_class" id="sample_id"></span>"` in c#

Answer (score 1):

After your edit you edited in this:

```
builder.Replace("<span class='sample_class' id='sample_id'></span>", generatedHTMLtable);
```

But that isn't the same as:

```
<span class="sample_class" id="sample_id"></span>
```

The 1st has `'` and the second has `"` to fix this use it like this:

```
builder.Replace("<span class=\"sample_class\" id=\"sample_id\"></span>", generatedHTMLtable);
```

This way you can put `"` inside a string, you're escaping it with `\`

Comment: thanks a lot working fine, I tried as you said it's getting replacing

Comment: @ShakirAhamed Did you have to change the code in the `ReplacePlaceholder()` method? When I ran the code above, it outputs `System.IO.StringReader`, instead of your replaced string

Comment: @DaveS I did not, I only tested it with a simple replace as that seemed to be the issue. But what you're noting is a problem too so good thinking!

Comment: @ShakirAhamed If it is working fine why did you un-accept, you don't have to accept my answer but I'd like to know?

Comment: @EpicKip I un-accept because, I have use different approach to replace the HTML tag,  I have added as an answer what I have did so far, But I have up-vote for your answer